# Bibtex - Missing '$' inserted?

Tags: bibtex, biber

I'm using biber to make my first bibliography and I'm running into lots of problems, most of them are solved but I can't fix this one. I continuously get an error message : Missing '$' inserted, on the line right after `\printbibliography`
Here's a sample from my bibliography, everything except the inproceedings is a similar online reference:

```
@online{FC,
    title = "Flight Controllers : The Processor Behind Every Multirotor Flight",
    author = "Clym Montgomery",
    year = "2014",
    url = {http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/multi-rotor-quadcopter-fpv,3828-2.html},
    note = "Accessed : October 27 2016"
}

@inproceedings{PID_algorithm,
    title = "A Fractional Order PID Tuning Algorithm for A Class of Fractional Order Plants",
    author = "Chunna Zhao and Dingyiu Xue and YanQuan Chen",
    year = "2005",
    booktitle = "International Conference on Mechatronics and Automation",
}
```

I'm using biber and I haven't defined a style, AFAIK I'm not supposed to/don't have to when using biber. Do I have to escape certain characters that I'm not escaping, or is something else wrong? I've found other questions solved because you don't need to escape the underscores.

edit : Just this bib entry :

```
@online{blheli_s,
    title = "BLHeli_s - Smooth as Silk",
    year = "2016",
    url = {https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2640796},
    note = "Accessed : October 27 2016"
}
```

still raises the error (after deleting the bib database and rerunning latexmk)

Comment: I see nothing that could raise the error. The usual suspects are URLs with underscore. Try isolating the bad entry.

Comment: I do have other url's with underscores. Is there a way to comment out in the .bib file to make my life easier?

Answer (score 1):

It was the underscore in BLHeli_S - I was too focused on the url's that I didn't look at the suspect title of the article.